# Can I assign a function to a variable?

Tags: powershell

is it correct that I cannot assign a function to a variable - like:

```
     $h = {ID="x1";readStream=$Null;... }
     ...
     $h.readStream = function{ ... }
```

Thanks!

P.S. @ A.Wiechers: To me it would help a lot if ALL the Title has at first entry the prg.-langague the question is about!! For this question I have to open only needles hints which I would have been able to skip if e.g. "Can I assign a function to a variable for use within another function? 1" would start with "Python" - the entry of the tags do NOT filter the StackExchange-suggestions! This would even help to prevent duplicate entries just because the titles are similar!!

Comment: May I know who gave me -2? Mr. Anonymous? May he be able to explain?

Comment: If the downvotes were for not putting 'powershell' into the title I think thats a bit rough given its not a settled science: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use a scriptblock.

let's take a really simple example : I want to multiply two integers in my function :

just do something like :

```
$h = @ {ID="x1" ; DoStuff = $Null }
$h.DoStuff = { $args[0] * $args[1] }
# note that $h = @{ID="x1" ; DoStuff = {$args[0] * $args[1]} } works as well


# Invoke your block : 
& $h.DoStuff 6 7

# or 
$h.DoStuff.Invoke(6,7)
```

Comment: Thank you! Like a function but without 'function' and the name!