# Powershell format string with output from function

Tags: function, powershell, variables

Hey guys I am having trouble figuring out how to convert the following function (which requires an input) into a variable

```
 function Convert-ToLetters ([parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][int] $value)  {
   $currVal = $value;
   $returnVal = '';
   while ($currVal -ge 26) {
      $returnVal = [char](($currVal) % 26 + 65) + $returnVal;
      $currVal =  [int][math]::Floor($currVal / 26)
   }
  $returnVal = [char](($currVal) + 64) + $returnVal;

     return $returnVal
  }
```

What this Function does is to convert a number into letters.

Now what I want to achieve is to somehow do this:

```
$convert2letter = Convert-ToLetters()
```

So that I can do something like

```
$WR= "$convert2letter($CValue1)" + "-" + "$convert2letter($CValue2)" + "-" + "3"
```

But Powershell isnt allowing me to do $convert2letter

So what can I do here?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798389/can-i-assign-a-function-to-a-variable

Comment: Why would you do it like this? Why not just call the function inside your string?

Comment: Thanks.... but maybe because my brain is just failing today... I could not figure out how to apply it here...even though I recognize it is VERY relevant and most probably the solution to my problem... I am sorry...

Comment: @Matt I am not sure what you mean.... my problem is that if I do a "Convertto-Letter($Cvalue1)" + "-" + "Convertto-Letter($Cvalue1)" + "-" + "3" ......... ill get a  result of     Convert-ToLetters(5)-Convert-ToLetters(21)-3   instead of say E-U-3

Comment: No need to put solutions in the question. That is what the answers are for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more information for justifying it I would think instead of this:

> ```
> $WR= "$convert2letter($CValue1)" + "-" + "$convert2letter($CValue2)" + "-" + "3"
> ```

You should just be doing this:

```
$WR = "$(Convert-ToLetters $CValue1)-$(Convert-ToLetters $CValue2)-3"
```

which uses subexpressions. Or use the format operator

```
$WR = "{0}-{1}-3" -f (Convert-ToLetters $CValue1), (Convert-ToLetters $CValue2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! .... I cant believe I was forgetting something so simple.....I ended up just doing $WR = "$(Convert-toletters $Cvalue1)" + "-" + "$Convert-toletters $Cvalue2" + "-" + "3"   .... Man I must be becoming really stupid today

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you are saying you want to invoke a function whose name is stored in a variable. One way to do this is by embedding a subexpression - `$()` - in a string and use the invocation/call operator - `&` to execute the function. For example:

```
function T {
  param(
    $a
  )
  "Result = $a"
}

$fn = "T"
"We want $(& $fn Test)"
```

Output:

```
We want Result = Test
```

Answer (score 1):

```
New-Alias -Name `$convert2letter -Value Convert-ToLetters
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, this doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: maybe it isnt something allowed in Powershell.... I was trying to make a script where I do several $WR...which is an alpha numeric "address"... but the source output that I originally get is numeric than Alphabetical in some parts...so I have to convert them.... i just wanted to see if I can somehow set $convert2letter as just the function without value.... since you cant use " " when typing the function with value

Comment: but why? why can't you call the function?

Comment: when I try ......   I get   

 + $convert2letter = Convert-ToLetters()
+                                     ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression